# Exchange Management Console Connecting to the Wrong Server

Tags: console, exchange-server

I'm new to MS Exchange, I've apparently made some error during its installation and now when I try to open the Exchange Management Console and I click on the Microsoft Exchange On-Premises tree item on the left, I get the following error:
"[servername.domainname.com] Connecting to the remote server failed with the following error message: The WinRM client cannot complete the operation within the time specified. Check if the machine name is valid and is reachable...."

I know that the servername is wrong, so how do I change it and have the Exchange Management Console connect automatically by default to the right server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close EMC

Under `C:\users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC\Exchange Management Console\` there is a config file named `Exchange Management Console`. Delete it.

In the registry under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Exchangeserver\v14\AdminTools\NodeStructureSettings` delete the value `NodeStructureSettings`

Found at http://lyncdup.com/2011/11/exchange-management-console-pointing-to-wrong-server-the-attempt-to-connect-to-httpserver-domain-compowershell-using-kerberos-authentication-failed/

Answer (score 1):

good starting point about troubleshooting Exchange 2010 WinRM issues:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/02/04/3409289.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The information [servername.domainname.com] ist stored in you userprofile. You might want to delete it.

I encounterd that error after i removed one of our exchange server. The Exchange Managment Console (EMC) keept trying to connect to the old server. After deleting the userprofile, the emc started to search for a valid exchange server and found the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was unsuccessful in the recommended answer here, along with another suggestiong to delete the user account folder in C:.

**However**, I finally found an acceptable workaround. I was able to open Exchange Management Shell and identify which on premise exchange server it was connecting. I took that FQDN and used it to add another Exchange Forest in EMC. The disfunctional forest is still there, but I just ignore it and use the new one. Worked like a charm. I don't particularly going outside of PowerShell, so it wasn't bothering me, but other users needed this as they absolutely dread the shell environment.